# Basic authentication in axios

Tags: javascript, axios, basic-authentication

I've got an problem with basic authentication with axios, i know axios have a dedicated option for this. But it doesn't work in my implementation. I've create an Axios instance, with the auth parameters included, but i still get an 401 (Unauthorized). When i remove the password from the server, the api calls are working.

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
    auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    }
});

instance.CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
instance.isCancel = axios.isCancel;

instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
}, (error) => {
    error.response = {
        success: false,
        message: {
            'type': 'error',
            'message': i18n.t('sentence.global.error.message')
        }
    };

    return Promise.reject({
        ...error
    });
});

export default instance;
```

I also tried this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
},{ 
    auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    });
}

....

export default instance;
```

I also tried prefixing the apiurl with username:password@apiurl.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you have the credentials wrong to me... have you attempted to access this resource manually?

Comment: @shadow yes i have correct credentials, when i access my application, the basic auth popup shows and when i enter the same credentials i'm connected to the api.

Comment: Have you tried it with providing the header "Authorization: Basic ..." and replace the dots with a "username:password" in base64 encoded string?